# MathJax won't render 'bold' faces

Tags: bold, mathjax

I recently implemented LaTeX on my website. I'm displaying my equations using MathJax. I have a problem displaying bold faces.

This is my latex syntax:

```
[latex] \text{{\bf 1 calorie} = amount of energy required to raise the temperature of {\bf 1 gram} of water by 1 degree Celsius.} [/latex]
```

I'm not sure if it is a browser issue or an issue with MathJax itself.

EDIT: Here is how MathJax renders: http://bit.ly/1l0v6p5

Comment: While [tag:MathJax] uses LaTeX syntax, it uses Javascript and HTML's DOM model rather than TeX technology, making it mostly off topic for this site. You might try instead searching among the [questions tagged with mathjax on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mathjax), or in the official [mathjax-users](https://groups.google.com/forum/mathjax-users) Google group.

Comment: Although MathJaX uses an input syntax based on LaTeX, it does not use TeX internally and so questions about MathJaX are usually not TeX-related and thus are off-topic for this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that MathJax interprets `\textbf` as a text if enclosed inside `\text`.
Corrected syntax: `[latex]\textbf{1 calorie} \text{ = amount of energy required to raise the temperature of } \textbf{1 gram} \text { of water by 1 degree Celsius.}[/latex]` works :)